# Angular - input predictive values calling api

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a predictive input that shows some results calling to my API, now I call the API everytime the user types a letter (keyup), but I want the function to call the api each 2 seconds.

```
 setTimeout(()=>{
    service.APIcall().subscibe();

  },2000);
```

This is what I have tryed, but it waits 2 seconds and calls the API the same amount of times.

Comment: The docs have an example using rxjs operators https://angular.io/guide/practical-observable-usage

Comment: Did you try `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`? `setInterval` repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call

Comment: You'll probably want to debounce these requests as well.  I would look in to that.

Answer (score 0):

A better way will be using an array and then send each letter and wait for 2 seconds between each result from the API.

```
myStringArray: String[] = [];

public onKeyDown($event: theEvent(Iforgot)): void {
  myStringArray.push($event.target.value);
}

// check when the user finished to enter keys
private async sendHttpRequest(): void {
 for (let letter in myStringArray) {
   const response = await service.APIcall().toPromise();
   setTimeout(await sendHttpRequest, 2000)
 }
}
```